# How to handle special characters in fuzzy search query

Tags: php, search, solr

So my solr query is implemented in two parts,first query does an exact search if there are no results found for exact then it goes to the second query that does a fuzzy search.
every things works fine but in situations like-->A user enters "burg +"
So in exact search no records will come,so second query is called to do a fuzzy search.Now comes the problem my fuzzy query does not understand special characters like +,-* which throws and error.If i dont pass special characters it works fine.  But in real world a user can put characters with their search,which will throw an error.
Now iam stuck in this and dont know how to resolve this issue.
This is how my exact search query looks like

```
$query1="(business_name:$data*^100 OR city_name:$data*^1 OR   
locality_name:$data*^6 OR business_search_tag_name:$data*^8 OR 
type_name:$data*^7) AND (business_active_flag:1) AND 
(business_visible_flag:1) AND (delete_status_businessmasters:0)";
```

This is how my fuzzy query looks like

```
$query2='(_query_:%20"{!complexphrase%20qf=business_name^100+type_name^0.4+locality_name^6%27}%20'.$url_new.')AND(business_active_flag:1)AND(business_point:[1.5 TO 2.0])&q.op=AND&wt=json&indent=true';
```

This is the error iam getting

```
 Cannot parse ' must~1 *~N': '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery
```

Iam new to solr and dont know how to tackle this situation.

Details of what iam using

Solrphpclient

php

solr 4.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so i see that you are using solrphpclient.You need to make changes in the service.php file so that these special characters get replaced to either blank or what ever you want.
This will take care of the problem you are facing

```
$params=str_replace("%", "", $params);
$params=str_replace("*", "", $params);
$params=str_replace("&", "", $params);
```

you need to put this in the search function or inside you custom function which i assume you are using for the fuzzy query